# Use of variable stores and or groups seems to be causing a crash

Tags: keyboard, keyman, keyman-developer

I tried implementing the variable store function to switch groups in a keyboard layout I developed, only for them to fail to implement in real use. To give you an idea, I'll write the gist of it in pseudocode

> begin group(main)
>
> group(main)
>
> store(mode) 'off'
>
> if(mode='off') > use(off)
> if(mode='on') > use(on)
>
> group(on) using keys
>
> '+ {key} > set(mode='off')
>
> group(off) using keys
>
> - {key} > set(mode='on')

Now When I implemented this on my computer after I reset said computer, I found it wouldn't actually use the different group when I actually installed the keyboard. Stranger yet, when I used the save function to save the variable stores, It cause the keyboard and whatever app I was using it in, to crash.

I did a bit of looking and found that my antivirus program (MCafee livesafe) was quarantining the crashpad_handler.exe files in the keyman installation folders. So after getting them back in my system and repairing the installation, I thought that would solve the problem, but it didn't.

Anybody else experiencing this? What did you do to solve it? For reference, everything was working fine before I reset my PC.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This [post](https://community.software.sil.org/t/keyman-15-mcafee-claims-virus/6537/3) on the Keyman community site might be related.